# Installing Linux on spare SSD

Tags: linux, debian, partition, ssd, debian-installer

I installed linux distribution (a debian-based one,called pardus) on HP EliteBook Folio 1040 G2 Notebook PC (http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/Laptops/hp-elitebook-folio-1040-g2-f6r38av-1) and it has a spare ssd drive. I couldn't boot from ssd and I got error page with this :

> boot device not found
>   harddisk - (3f0)

I also made the disk partition but it didn't work 
Thank you

Comment: Legacy or UEFi boot?

Answer (score 0):

Does your hard disk have an EFI partition?  I've seen this error, even when setting the bios to legacy mode, if there is no EFI partition.

A simple way of checking is to download a recent ubuntu, install it and inspect the partition table.  You should then be able to install pardus over the top of ubuntu, but don't allow it to delete the EFI partition (probably the first one).

Comment: Yes it has EFI partition and I have also made the partition and create \boot 
but it didn't work. I couldn't boot that